Ubuntu is confused: An upgrade from 'noble' to 'jammy' is not supported with this tool
I am aware of the 24.04.1 troubles at roll out.
Earlier this year I set up a fresh Jammy LTS Ubuntu instance on a new computer. I waited with the upgrade until a few days ago when it prompted me to upgrade to Noble. I thought any and all kinks were ironed out, especially since this is a very vanilla hardware (and software) environment. Anyway some things broke:
When I run Software Updater now, sometimes the application crashes, sometimes it'll report this:

I go for "Partial Upgrade", which quickly throws this error message:

Now I'm new to Ubuntu, but even I know the order in this error is wrong. I can't resolve this going apt update & apt upgrade. Some other things broke as well. ie: double clicking on an encrypted file within a zip (default will no longer prompt for password input, I have to manually extract the respective files. Just weird. Do you have any ideas for me as to how I can restore the updater?
The single piece of software I installe from outside of Ubuntu's own snap basket is SABnzbd.
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for [XXX]: 
Hit:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                          
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
673 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

then, if I run sudo apt upgrade, none of said packages are upgraded.
I checked against Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade and when I follow the instructions there to fix /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources, I find that /etc/apt/sources.list contains only noble and no jammy BUT there is no /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources file.
So I cd to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and ran dir.
It contains: jcfp-ubuntu-nobetas-jammy.list, jcfp-ubuntu-nobetas-jammy.list.save, and jcfp-ubuntu-nobetas-jammy.list.distUpgrade.

"Partial Upgrades" are usually a Real Bad Idea and basically just tell you that your package system is broken when they get offered up.  If you open a terminal and give the command sudo apt update the output will be helpful for diagnosis, please paste it into your question, not as a screenshot, but as a copy and paste of the text.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
